# Exclude folders per run configuration - IntelliJ UE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath, run-configuration

I have two run configurations for a project with two modules in it.

I want to exclude for both run configurations different module folders (folders in that module) - to say a different classpath for every run configuration.

I could exclude the desired folders manually every time before running the application, but that's a bit dowdy.

Is there a way to edit the classpath per run configuration in IntelliJ UE?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to solve this is to set up your module files so that each of the folders you're trying to exclude belongs to a separate module, and to set up each run configuration so that the module specified in its settings only depends on the module containing the folder needed for that particular configuration.